# Checkstyle-Idea plugin with Android Studio

Tags: plugins, android-studio, checkstyle

With the latest version of the plugin, I have found that it is incompatible with Android Studio since it requires Java 8. It recommends the JetBrains IDE with pre bundled Java 8 for Mac users.

Has anyone found a way to get this plugin working with Android Studio? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new enviroment variable for your current User named JAVA_HOME pointing to your Java 8 installation.

Comment: Not sure I follow - where am I creating the variable? In preferences?

Comment: No, you have to add it to the PATH enviroment variable in your OS. See https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa1067/_index.html